# Why does the NODE_DELETE configuration needs to specify a connection?

Tags: relayjs

I'm currently building a mutation that deletes a node.
I looked into the `NODE_DELETE` mutator configuration, but it specifies it needs a `parentName`, `parentID` and `connectionName`.

Why does deleting a node needs theses fields ? As Relay uses global IDs, it should be fairly easy to delete a node from all connections and/or all fields it is being referenced in.

See the documentation :
[Relay NODE_DELETE documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#node-delete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. **Those fields are redundant for the purpose of deleting node from data store**, only `config.deletedIDFieldName` is used during such operation (details in [writeRelayUpdatePayload](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/7110c68f437391ad1ee54ab2c84fd8896a8662fb/src/traversal/writeRelayUpdatePayload.js#L114) module).

However **you can't leave other fields unfilled, because they are still required during validation** of your mutation that extends `RelayMutation` class. I have no idea where this inconsistency comes from, but it's worth noting that Relay team changed the direction of development and `RelayMutation` will get deprecated.

> `RelayMutation` and fat/tracked queries. Future releases will deprecate
>   this API in favor of a static mutation API. We recommend using
>   [`RelayGraphQLMutation`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-graphql-mutation.html) to ease the transition to new mutations.

source: [Related issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1369)

After quick look in Relay's source it seems this transitional API does not use the old method of configs validation, but I haven't got a chance to experiment with it yet, so you can confirm it yourself.